# jQuery Plugin - Image Gallery (Fade In / Fade Out)

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, gallery

I have an inline list with an image gallery horizontally centralized, but sometimes this gallery can have a width bigger than the browser window, so some images will not be visible.

[image]

You guys can also check it online here: http://3bum.com

If the gallery width is bigger than the browser window, I would like to every 3 seconds fade out an image the user **can** see and fade in, at the same time and place, an image he **cant** see, avoid replace the same image, only after replacing all others and stop it when the mouse is over the gallery.

I'm not a javascript expert, so here is what I've done so far: I can switch two random images, but first I fade out one, than fade in the other, it's doesn't fade out and fade in at the same time and it doesnt check if the images are already visible or not. And stop the fade in/fade out if the mouse is over it.

The plugin:

```
$.fn.fader = function ()
{
    var gallery = $(this),
        images = [];

    gallery.css(
        {
            marginLeft: '-' + (this.width() / 2) + 'px',
            visibility: 'visible'
        }).find('a').each(function ()
        {
            images.push($(this));
        });

    var fade = setInterval(function ()
    {
        fadeImages();
    }, 5000);

    var fadeImages = function ()
    {
        images.sort(function ()
        {
            return 0.5 - Math.random()
        });

        imagesToFade = images.slice(0, 2);

        var temporarySrc = imagesToFade[0].find('img').attr('src'),
            temporaryHref = imagesToFade[0].attr('href');

        switchImages(imagesToFade[0], imagesToFade[1].find('img').attr('src'));
        switchImages(imagesToFade[1], temporarySrc);

        switchLinks(imagesToFade[0], imagesToFade[1].attr('href'));
        switchLinks(imagesToFade[1], temporaryHref);
    }

    var switchImages = function (oldImage, newImage)
    {
        oldImage.find('img').animate(
            {
                opacity: 0.0
            }, 1000, function ()
            {
                oldImage.find('img').attr('src', newImage).animate(
                    {
                        opacity: 0.6
                    }, 1000);
            });
    }

    var switchLinks = function (oldImage, newImage)
    {
        oldImage.attr('href', newImage);
    }

    gallery.mouseover(function ()
    {
        clearInterval(fade);
    }).mouseout(function ()
        {
            fade = setInterval(function ()
            {
                fadeImages();
            }, 5000);
        })


};
```

The html:

```
<section class="portfolio">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8199/8220132885_9e693356e9_b.jpg">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8199/8220132885_9e693356e9_m.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8481/8215602321_69d9939b8b_b.jpg">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8481/8215602321_69d9939b8b_m.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8200/8220393833_e52cabfe80_b.jpg">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8200/8220393833_e52cabfe80_m.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8200/8207750975_bd288a2a1f_b.jpg">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8200/8207750975_bd288a2a1f_m.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8522/8478415115_152c6f5e55_b.jpg">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8522/8478415115_152c6f5e55_m.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8366/8483546751_86494ae914_b.jpg">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8366/8483546751_86494ae914_m.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_b.jpg">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_m.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="portfolio" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7152/6394238505_c94fdd1d89_b.jpg">
                <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7152/6394238505_c94fdd1d89_m.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, your site isn't being made public yet, the link just sends us to a godaddy.com page.

One thing that might help, you can make query selectors specific to visible or hidden elements, for example:

```
$("img:hidden").show();
```

or

```
$("img:visible").hide()
```

Hope that helps you continue building on top of what you already have...good luck!